# error MSB4064: The "BuildAgentUri" parameter is not supported by the "WorkspaceItemConverterTask" task

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

Today, I ran few updates for Visual Studio 2013 on our build machine

- Visual Studio 2013 Update 5
- NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio (2.8.60723.765)
- [* We do not have any other versions of Visual Studio installed on it at the moment]

After doing so, we noticed that bunch of TypeScript files were removed and test builds failed as a result. We re-installed TypeScript, and the issue was resolved.

Then we began having issues with the Team Build, as per below:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   **> (1704): The "BuildAgentUri" parameter is not supported by the
>   "GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems" task. Verify the parameter exists on
>   the task, and it is a settable public instance property.**
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   (1701): The "GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems" task could not be
>   initialized with its input parameters.
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   **> (1791): The "BuildAgentUri" parameter is not supported by the
>   "WorkspaceItemConverterTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the
>   task, and it is a settable public instance property.**
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets
>   (1701): The "GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems" task could not be
>   initialized with its input parameters.

The BuildAgentUri parameter is being set and is indeed being accessed in that line. I did find few posts related to this issue, including the following:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765469/build-fails-with-error-on-createworkspacetask-and-missing-parameter-buildagenturi

We had multiple versions of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll on the build machine (v10.0.0 and v12.0.0), so we tried removing version 10.0.0 from GAC; this, however, resulted in the following reference issues:

> TF209001: An error occurred while processing Error event for
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets:
>   **Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow, Version=10.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies.** The system cannot find the file specified..

I've looked for references to version 10.0.0, including in the .xaml workflow template, but I just could not find it. I also had a look at our Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file and it did not seemed to be incorrectly re-formatted or organized, as another poster on stackoverflow had suggested.

Overall, I am incredibly confused about how a relatively small-scale update resulted in this. Should I add version 10.0.0 of Build.Workflow.dll back to GAC and attempt to fix the initial issue, or should I attempt resolve the second one that rose when we removed version 10.0.0?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you using an older build process template?

Comment: I don't think so, because none of the namespace declarations in the process template have version=10.0.0 and when I go to "Arguments" > "ArgumentType" > "Browse for other Types", none of the relevant types have version 10.0.0. (They are all 12.0.0.) Is there another way I need to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by removing BuildAgentUri as a parameter for all tasks in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file - GenCheckinNotesUpdateWorkItems, WorkspaceItemConverterTask, etc. I had just missed a reference the first time I had gone through it. I guess the version of the assembly that the task being derived from (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.ProcessComponents.dll) doesn't have BuildAgentUri as a defined parameter? There were some other issues I had to resolve for our build configurations, but for most people, this should hopefully be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't think it is a good idea to uninstall version 10.0.0 Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll from GAC.

Secondly, I found that many other community members get the similar errors as you, and the issue is resolved via reinstalling TFS. Please check answers in this link for the details: http://www.developerblogger.com/1198_12609329/

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that post but that was not the case - the mentioned section in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets had not been modified by the update. It seems pretty odd to have to uninstall and reinstall TFS after a minor VS upgrade. At any rate, I have found a solution.